# Change the file format using browser-image-compression library in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, image-compression

In this example I am using the filetype option as `.png` but its not working as expected.

```
import imageCompression from 'browser-image-compression';

const compressImage = async (pic) => {
  const options = {
    maxSizeMB: 1,
    maxWidthOrHeight: 1024,
    useWebWorker: true,
    fileType: '.png',
  };

  const compressedPic = await imageCompression(pic, options);
  console.log('compressed', compressedPic.size);
  console.log('compressd pic title', compressedPic.name);
};
```

Comment: May be try `fileType: 'image/png'`

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

In 'browser-image-compression' sources you can see that

```
@param {string} [options.fileType] - default to be the original mime type from the image file
```

You should use file mime type rather than `.png` extension, so try to use `image/png` instead.